# How to send litter '&' as url parameter - swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a code to update name of department in the database .. I use this encoding code :

```
        let myurlstring="http:example/updateDepartment.php?deptName="+"\(deptName)"+"&id="+"\(deptID)"

    let escapedString = myurlstring.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)


    let myUrl = URL(string:escapedString!)!
```

It works very well , but when `deptName` string contains this litter `&` it's not working.

example1 : send request with `deptName = "CIT and Network"` it will work .

example2 : send request with `deptName = "CIT & Network"` will be in the database as only "CIT" any litter after `&` will be skipped.

any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`URLComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlcomponents) + [`URLQueryItem`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlqueryitem/) instead. It can be used to encode the query part from structured input:

```
var comp = URLComponents(string: "http://example.com")!
comp.path = "/some path to/update.php"
comp.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "deptName", value: "CIT & Network"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "id", value: "123456"),
]

let url = comp.url!
print(url)
// http://example.com/some%20path%20to/update.php?deptName=CIT%20%26%20Network&id=123456
```

Comment: Thank you , I tried this but when the code reach `var comp` .... I got : unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: I got another problem .. yes it works but in the database I see "&amp" instead of '&' .. print of my url : deptName=CIT%20%26%20Network&id=3

Comment: @Zizoo How do you query the result from the database? And your print does not have any `&amp;`.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: @Zizoo Where do you see the `&amp;`, your comment does not contain any `&amp;`.

Comment: I'm using mysqlworkbench to select from tables , and I see the saved '&' from my app as "&amp;" I did update the name from my app to CIT&NETWORK and I see it in the database as "CIT&amp;NETWORK"

Comment: @Zizoo OK. Is it possible that your have XML-escaped the URL when you insert it into the MySQL database? In this piece of code there is no way an `&amp;` can appear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124068/discussion-between-zizoo-and-kennytm).